# How to solve Laravel 5 nesting level of '100' reached aborting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, adminlte

in Laravel 5 I installed AdminLTE template. This template provide the routes documentation https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/blob/master/src/Http/routes.php. But I make some changes in the route because I want default login route

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout'); 
});
```

if I use this I am facing following error

> FatalErrorException in Factory.php line 5: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

But I remove middleware so working fine. So what is my problem or I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first open your xdebug conf file from here `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

then set your xdebug nesting level more than 100 as you want `xdebug.max_nesting_level=500`